# Как эмулировать нажатие кнопки по нажатию на другую кнопку?

Tags: javascript

Как сымитировать нажатие на кнопку нажатием по другой кнопку?

```css
.hider-recipient {
display: block;
margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button class="hider">Нажать на "Кнопку 1"</button>
<button class="hider-recipient">Кнопка 1</button>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
function triggerButton1Click() {
  document.querySelector(".hider-recipient").dispatchEvent(new Event("click"));
}
```

```css
.hider-recipient {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button class="hider" onclick="triggerButton1Click()">Нажать на "Кнопку 1"</button>
<button class="hider-recipient" onclick="console.log('Кнопка 1 clicked')">Кнопка 1</button>
```

Comment: вариант `document.querySelector(".hider-recipient").click()` для самых ленивых

Comment: Выдает ошибку `"Uncaught ReferenceError: triggerButton1Click is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):957)"`

Comment: @QuickBrownFox Нет, не выдает. Нажмите кнопку "Выполнить код" в ответе.

Answer (score 4):

```js
    window.onload = function () {
        let but1 = document.getElementsByClassName('hider')[0]; // Получаем элемент по классу
        let but2 = document.getElementsByClassName('hider-recipient')[0];  // Получаем элемент по классу

        but1.addEventListener('click', function () { // При нажатии первой кнопки
            but2.click(); // нажимаем вторую
        });
        but2.addEventListener('click', function () { // Для демонстрации - при нажатии на вторую кнопку
            console.log('Вторая кнопка нажата'); // выводим сообщение в консоль
        })
    }
```

```html
<style>
    .hider-recipient {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
</style>
<button class="hider">Нажать на "Кнопку 1"</button>
<button class="hider-recipient">Кнопка 1</button>
```